# Disabling date for selection in datepicker in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I hve two datepickers namely : dtpFromDate and dtpToDate.

Now, I want that if the user has selected some date in dtpFromDate then he should not be able to select the dates prior to the selected date in the other date control i.e. dtpToDate

What I have done is this

```
    void dtpFromSearch_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dtpFromSearch.Text) && dtpFromSearch.SelectedDate!=DateTime.MinValue))
        {
            dtpToSearch.DisplayDateStart=dtpFromSearch.SelectedDate;
        }
    }
```

This does not disable the previous dates in dtpToDate control. Can anyone help. **I don't want to handle it with a validation**

Comment: What was the default value of `dtpFromDate`?

Comment: this.dtpFromSearch.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
            this.dtpToSearch.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(7);

Comment: This i did on Page Load.

Answer (score 1):

so you can do the following,

Bind the `SelectedDate` property of `dtpFromSearch` to the `DisplayDateStart` property of `dtpToSearch` and place a converter on this...

In the Converter, check the `SelectedDate` is `Today` then you can return the Date as you want to start.. and also for end Date, Bind the same with `DisplayDateEnd`...

Get more info about the Display dates below link..

- [DatePicker.DisplayDateStart Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.displaydatestart%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
- [DatePicker.DisplayDateEnd Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.displaydateend.aspx)

Comment: I don't want to diable the whole datepicker... it's the date ..for example if i have 18 Feb selected in dtpfromDate then all the dates prior to 18 Feb in dtpToDate should be disabled for selection